# Is there any sense in separating Identity models from business models to separate projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

A rather newbie question about best ASP.NET MVC solution architecture

Is there any sense in separating Identity models from business models to separate projects?

Are there any bigger advantages?

Thanks for help

Comment: Business models have business logic in them. Business models are for representing the business domain. Entity models are for database modelling and do not have business rules in them. They represent your database.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41512711/ddd-and-entity-framework-classes/41513520#41513520) for more details.

Comment: What do you mean by identity models?

Comment: By Identity Models, I mean all the UserRoles, UserModels, Authorizations and stuff connected with asp.identity.

And as it goes on, it would mean two db contexts in two separate projs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Coding Yoshi Business models should only have Business Logic In them. I believe that you are asking if you should keep Identity Models and if your Identity Models are for Security Logic you for sure should have Identity Models encapsulated from other Business Logic. This will allow for Business Protection and if you need to update the Security for any reason you have at least possible layer from all Business Rules and Possible Business Secrets. Check out [this](https://identityserver.io/) link for best practices for Identity answers.